# TYPO3 TMENU each special.value wrap

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I dont come forth. I want to wrap each given PID in its own unique wrap.

Here my code:

```
menutab.list = HMENU
menutab.list.special = directory
menutab.list.special.value = 7,8,9,10,11,12,13
menutab.list.1 = TMENU
menutab.list.1.wrap = <div>|</div>
...
```

So thats working fine. I get every submenu of given PIDs but now i'm searching for something like that:

```
menutab.list.special.value.wrap = <div id="current PID!"> | </div>
```

I hope someone understand my issue. 
Big thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends which field you would like to display, but basically any field from the page record can be displayed into the output.

```
menutab.list = HMENU
menutab.list {
    special = directory
    special.value = 7,8,9,10,11,12,13
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        # stdWrap2 wraps the whole item, including the link
        NO.stdWrap2.dataWrap = <div id="p{field:uid}">|</div>
    }
}
```

This will give the following output:

```
<div id="p26"><a href="test-0/">Test 0</a></div>
<div id="p27"><a href="test-1/">Test 1</a></div>
<div id="p30"><a href="test-2/">Test 2</a></div>
<div id="p31"><a href="test-3/">Test 3</a></div>
<div id="p35"><a href="test-4/">Test 4</a></div>
<div id="p36"><a href="test-5/">Test 5</a></div>
<div id="p37"><a href="test-6/">Test 6</a></div>
```

For more options, please take a look at the TSref and the stdWrap functions.

TSref
http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.4.0/view/toc/0/

stdWrap
http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.4.0/view/1/5/#id2618234

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to do something like that, not sure of the syntax... :

```
menutab.list.1 = HMENU
menutab.list.1 {
  special = directory
  special.value = 7
  1 = TMENU
  1.wrap = <div id="7"> | </div>
}
menutab.list.2 < menutab.list.1
menutab.list.2.special.value = 8
menutab.list.2.1.wrap = <div id="8"> | </div>
...
```

Not the best solution, but can work